# How to get outermost parent UIView container?

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, guard, superview

How can I get grand gran parent view of my current `self` `UIView`, currently I'm using `self.superview?.superview?.superview?.superview?.superview?.superview?`

It looks kind of weird, instead of using above syntax is their any other way to get main `UIView` otherwise how can i preventing this optional chaining with `guard`?

Comment: I just want to `addSubview(mySubView)` as an overlay of all screen and when remove this subview i want my previous view stay same (like table view scrolled position stay same)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `guard` with a method that returns optional, (I assume that you are calling this from UIView custom class).

```
private func outerMostParent(view:UIView)-> UIView? {
    guard let parent  = superview?.superview?.superview?.superview?.superview?.superview
           else{
        return nil
    }
    return parent
}
```

and then you can do

```
self.outerMostParent(self)?.addSubview(yourSubview)
```